# Generics ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to write a method that returns the smallest element in an ArrayList so that in the test program i can call the method for Integer, String, Rational and Complex type list. I think i have an idea and it goes like this:

```
public static <E extends Comparable <E>> E minimum (ArrayList<E> list) {
```

But I dont exactly know how to start it like what goes in the method. Like I have the idea of what should be in the method im my head but I just cant seem to like bring it out. Any suggestions on how I should do it please?

Comment: Start implementing it with an array of integers as argument rather than a List of comparables. Then adapt the algorithm by using compareTo() rather than `<`. Note that what you're implementing already exists in the JDK (and you might thus look at the source code): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-

Comment: Can you please show me a sample of the code? Thank you.

Comment: No. Finding the minimum value in an array must be the very first algorithm using loops that I had to program in my entire life. It should be simple enough for you to find out, especially if you're learning generics, which are a much more complex matter. How do you find the smallest value in an array, by hand? BTW, if you want to cheat, you can just look at the java.util.Collections.min() source code.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you could just code it as below :

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E minimum(ArrayList<E> list) {
    return list.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
}
```